# htaccess rewrite url to 404 an invalid url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am re writing the url's from my site in the htaccess file by setting a condition rule.
example

```
    RewriteRule product/([a-zA-Z0-9-.]*)-([0-9]*).html$ /index.php?l=product_detail&p=$2
```

This works fine and it does the job, however since only the last number matters, the first wording can be anything!!

How can I perform a  check in the database if this is a valid wording and if not it should be redirected to a  404 page?

Comment: you will need to perform checks at `index.php`, please show code for that.

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot deal with databases directly, but you can use an external map file/script to do so: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Comment: ^ I like this approach because it doesn't run any PHP, I'm not sure, but it probably uses less resources.